# How to show proper set inclusion/exclusion? Please don't give me the solution.

Tags: real-analysis, notation, solution-verification, convention

I found this problem from an online source.

> [image]

I've just got two question

1) I think there is a typo in the solution, it should be $(x_n) \in \ell_1$ right?

2) I am guessing $c_0 \subsetneq \ell_\infty$ is already true because of the problem? Does the $\subset$ here actually mean "subset" or "subspace"? If they denote subspace, Ssouldn't the solution also show the three properties of a subspace or is that so bivous from the properties of sums and sequences (I can see it myself, for instance, $0$ belongs to all the sets) that you really don't need to show it?

FYI, I proved all of those myself already even though my proof is much longer and in more detail.

Comment: It looks like the author intends "$x$" and "$(x_n)$" to mean the same thing. So for (1), no, I don't think there is a typo. $x$ represents the sequence. For (2), I think the author specifically says "set inclusions", right? No mention of subspaces.

Comment: $\subset$ here means proper subset; "Show that we have the following proper *set inclusions.*" Since these are vector spaces the set inclusions automatically imply these are subspaces. It's trivial, but worth working out at least once, that they are indeed vector spaces.

Comment: @neuguy, subsets are not subspaces?